# Get new random image when button is clicked - android

Tags: android, image, random

I am developing an app that once a button is clicked I go to a new activity where 3 random images are set to an imageView. If the user does not like the 3 images selected, they can then click a button to generate 3 new random images. I am having two problems...

1. I have the imageView set to a specific size but when the images show up they are sometimes smaller and are showing horizontally. I would like them to show up vertically and all as the size of the imageView. How do I change the code to do this?
2. I am getting the new images to show up when I click the button but I am getting an error saying that I am running out of memory after I do it a few times. How do I change the code so I stop using all my memory?

Here is my code

```
public ImageView shirts;
public ImageView pants;
public ImageView shoes;
Button reload;
private Bitmap currentBitmap = null;
String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.suggested_outfit);
    shirts = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shirtImage);
    pants = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pantsImage);
    shoes = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shoesImage);

    shirts.setImageBitmap(getImage());
    pants.setImageBitmap(getImage());
    shoes.setImageBitmap(getImage());

    reload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getNewOutfit);
    reload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });
}


public Bitmap getImage () {
    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images,
            projection,"", null, ""
    );
    final ArrayList<String> imagesPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

        int dataColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            imagesPath.add(cur.getString(dataColumn));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    cur.close();
    final Random random = new Random();
    final int count = imagesPath.size();
    int number = random.nextInt(count);
    String path = imagesPath.get(number);

    currentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

    return currentBitmap;
}
```

}

I read that it isn't good practice to reload the activity but I can't figure out a way to generate 3 new random images. I am open for any suggestions if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining images through an `onClick` method would have to have

```
do {
   String path = cur.getString(dataColumn);
   if(path.contains("yourDirectory")){ //in your case, your image directory
      imagesPath.add(path);
   }
} while (cur.moveToNext());
```

within the requested intent/activity

Answer (score 0):

Decoding Bitmap consumes much memory, on your code you decode Bitmap many times when click button maybe causes OutOfMemory. Try to decode all your Bitmap once times and save them to a list. When a click to generate random Bitmap, you create random index of the list Bitmap and retrieve object by that index. Hope this help!

Comment: Not sure how to do that since I reload the activity each time the button is pressed. Even if i save it to a list isn't it going to keep decoding the bitmap because I am refreshing the activity each time?

Comment: Why do you need restart activity, this is a expensive behavior, each time activity recreate Android OS need allocate resource again. You can create random Bitmap without to restart activity. Beside Bitmap size maybe causes OutOfMemory, try to rescale size of Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

you can use this utils: [image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
it has memory manager.and you can set imageview when image load completed.

Comment: I cannot download any packages. I need to write the code.

Comment: use BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null,  options) instead of using  BitmapFactory.decodeFile().decodeStream call the JNI>>nativeDecodeAsset() to decode Bitmap.